# dash doesn't refresh pages

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm trying to test the refresh page logic.

I read the manual:
https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

And wrote this simple code:

```
import datetime
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

def get_time():
    print("get time...")
    return datetime.datetime.now()


def serve_layout():
    return html.H1('The time is: ' + str(get_time()))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = dash.Dash()
    app.layout = serve_layout()
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

- I expected to see that every page refresh (`F5`) I will see the log "`get time...`",
  But I see this log only on startup and not on every refresh.
- What am I missing ?
- I want to wrote a logic that every page refresh (`F5`) the function `serve_layout` (and `get_time`) will be called.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are assigning the rendered layout instead of a function, which is needed to update on page refresh. Hence if you replace the line

```
app.layout = serve_layout()
```

with

```
app.layout = serve_layout
```

it should work as expected.

Comment: thank you very much. I just put the function of getting data into serve_layout, and It's work.